# Masterbrain Specialist Subject Round

Tags: knowledge, pattern

Daniel has reached the semi-final of Masterbrain, a TV show which features an intimidating setting and challenging questions, presented by the famous Morten Mortensson.

Daniel has achieved a high score in the general knowledge round and is about to answer questions on his specialist subject. The crowd falls silent as the round begins.

> **Morten:** What subscription-based music streaming service was launched in Hong Kong in 2006?
>   **Daniel:** Moov music.
>   **Morten:** Correct. Give me two words which begin with the letter 'P' and end with the letters 'SH'.
>   **Daniel:** "Push" or "Posh".
>   **Morten:** Correct. The sound made by a telephone to indicate an incoming call or text message is called a what?
>   **Daniel:** Ringtone.
>   **Morten:** Correct. American cops catch a suspect in possession of a large amount of drugs, what should they do next?
>   **Daniel:** Bust him.
>   **Morten:** Correct. Complete the title of this 1998 Indonesian political essay film directed and written by Garin Nugroho - "My Family, My Films and ..."
>   **Daniel:** "My Nation"
>   **Morten:** Correct. What is my favourite inverse trigonometric function?
>   **Daniel:** ...

**What is the answer to Morten's latest question?**
**What is Daniel's specialist subject?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to Morten's question is:

> The inverse sine function, or ARCSINE, which anagrams to **ARSENIC**.

We can observe that

> The other answers follow this trend as well!
>  MOOV MUSIC -> **MOSCOVIUM**
>  PUSH OR POSH -> **PHOSPHORUS**
>  RINGTONE -> **NITROGEN**
>  BUST HIM -> **BISMUTH**
>  MY NATION -> **ANTIMONY**

I initially guessed

> Chemistry

to be Daniel's specialist subject, but now I believe that it is instead

> **The nitrogen group** (Group 15 of the periodic table, where the elements stated above are found).

Comment: Yes, nice, the specialist subject is slightly more specific. When you get this, I'll award the green tick.

Comment: @hexomino I'm still not quite sure, but does the subject happen to be rot13(gur crevbqvp gnoyr)?

Comment: slightly more specific, look at where your answers are located on this.

Comment: edited, hopefully it's the right one now